# New user. Can't install updates because I don't know the pass word

Tags: updates

New user trying to update software but don't know the authentication pass word

Answer (score 0):

The authentication password is your own password.

You can change it in system preferences or using `passwd`.

Answer (score 0):

the authentication password is your current user password.

if you want to change the password to be sure use this command :

```
sudo passwd user_name
```

then click enter it will ask you for the new password and ask you to verify it

if you want to activate root user just use this command :

```
sudo passwd
```

without writing a user name and it will set password for root user and activate it
then you login with it in cmd by using this command :

```
sudo su -
```

and by then you wont use sudo any more and can use the root password for authentication

Answer (score 0):

- Start your computer
- In a **grub menu** which appear by default when your start your computer, select "advanced options for ubuntu"
- After that, select the option which states things like "recovery mode"
- Now You will be shown the recovery menu. In the recovery menu Select “root – Drop to root shell prompt
- Then command prompt will appear at the bottom of the screen. Type this following in the command prompt to show all the user of your computer

  `ls /home`
- Next type the following command at command prompt to mount with permissions

  `mount -rw -o remount /`
- Finally type `passwd username` in the command prompt. For example if the username you selected is Kevin, the command will be

  `passwd Kevin`
- It will ask you to reset password

  `Enter new UNIX Password:`

  `Retype new UNIX Password:`
- Make sure you see this message

  `Passwd:Password updated successfully`
- Just it ! Now restart your computer by type `reboot` in the command prompt